# Problem with footnotes in a two-column environment

Tags: footnotes, page-breaking, two-column

A particular problem connected to the position of footnotes. In a book I work on there are several passages that include two columns (quote and translation). Sometimes these two-column-passages contain several footnotes. Therefore I had to use the \footnotemark option (instead of the plain \footnote option) and write the \footnotetext at the end. Now, if the two column environment includes a pagebreak, all the footnotes appear on the second page, even if the footnotemarks belong to the first page, and they have all the same number (see example). I did some research to solve this special problem but was unsuccessful. It seems that the fact that it is a two-column-environment causes the problems. So there are two questions: 
1) how can I force LaTeX to position the footnotes of that environment on the page they belong to? 
2) how can I force LaTeX to count the footnote numbers correctly?
Thank you for any advice.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\footnotelayout{m}
\newcommand{\quotetwocolumns}[2]{\begin{adjustwidth}{7mm}{7mm}\setlength{\columnsep}{-5mm}\begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy {\small#1\par}\switchcolumn \sloppy {\small#2\par}\end{paracol}\end{adjustwidth}\vspace{3mm}}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1em}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{10pt plus 3pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}
\quotetwocolumns{
\lipsum[1] \footnotemark 
\lipsum[2] \footnotemark 
\lipsum[3] \footnotemark}
{\lipsum[4-6]}
\footnotetext{Footnote 1}
\footnotetext{Footnote 2} 
\footnotetext{Footnote 3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `reledmac` package?

Comment: I think the problem is `footmisc` here,  because it modifies parts of the Latex kernel. If you reject using `footmisc` your example compiles successfully and you can also reject using the `\footnotemark` directive, which is a rather tedious way to implement footnotes.